# JqGrid bug, buttons are shown twice

Tags: jquery, jqgrid

When I load JqGrid first time everything is ok. When I reload it, buttons are shown twice. How do I fix this? Is it a common problem with JqGrid? I can't post my screen to show it :-(

Comment: It is not a general problem in jqGrid. What do you mean under "reloading the grid"? You should post a code (modify and append you question with the code) which can be used to reproduce you problem. I think you call `navGrid` or `navButtonAdd` at any refresh.

Answer (score 0):

I have seen this before where I had a jqGrid on a jQuery Tab, and the jqGrid was initialized each time a particular tab page was shown. The fix in that particular instance was to use a variable to track when the grid was initialized, and only create it the first time the tab is shown.

Does that help at all? If not, perhaps you could provide more information about your grid and how you are reloading it.

Answer (score 0):

I had multiple  different grids on same page and my bug was having multiple html elements for pager with same id which i use to reference form jqGrid inside javascrpt file...

Solution: Have unique pagers inside HTML for jqGrids

```
<table id="gridTable1">
    <tr><td/></tr>
</table>
</div>
<div id="gridpager"> -- MUST be different => <div id="gridpager1">
</div>
<div id="custom">

<table id="gridTable2">
    <tr><td/></tr>
</table>
</div>
<div id="gridpager"> -- MUST be different => <div id="gridpager2">
</div>
<div id="custom">
```

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue and this is how I resolve it:

Several of my jqgrids were calling a shared function that extended the settings with default values.  In those extended settings I was setting the `pager` property to the div id that was being duplicated.  I shouldn't not have been doing this from the shared settings.  Once I removed the `pager` property from the extended settings and forced all the calling jqgrids to set their own `pager` property this issue was resolved.